# Multiple SELECTS with same condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with approximately 700 data with auto-incremental ID and with these fields:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| id | pos_1 | pos_2 | pos_3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1  |   9   |   2   |   3   |
| 2  |   3   |   2   |   9   |
| 3  |   1   |   4   |   3   |
| 4  |   1   |   2   |   3   |
| 5  |   5   |   1   |   6   |
| 6  |   1   |   2   |   3   |
| 7  |   8   |   2   |   0   |
| ...| ...   |  ...  |   ... |
| etc|   etc |   etc |   etc |
+------+------+------+------+
```

It happens that I always perform a query that contains several selects and a common condition, all united by "UNION" in this way:

```
select *
from listado T1
 where pos_1 = ***  and pos_2 = ***  and pos_3 = ***       and exists (
   select id
   from listado T2
   where
 T2.pos_1 = ***  and pos_2 = ***  and pos_3 = ***
and T2.id >= T1.id - 10
and T2.id <= T1.id + 10
and T1.id != T2.id )

 UNION

 select *
from listado T3
 where pos_1 = ***  and pos_2 = ***  and pos_3 = ***    and exists (
   select id
   from listado T4
   where
 T4.pos_1 = ***  and pos_2 = ***  and pos_3 = ***
and T4.id >= T3.id - 10
and T4.id <= T3.id + 10
and T3.id != T4.id )

 UNION

 select *
from listado T5
 where pos_1 = ***  and pos_2 = ***  and pos_3 = ***    and exists (
   select id
   from listado T6
   where
 T6.pos_1 = ***  and pos_2 = ***  and pos_3 = ***
and T6.id >= T5.id - 10
and T6.id <= T5.id + 10
and T5.id != T6.id )

 ORDER BY id ASC
```

In such a way that this query returns the rows that match the numbers that I have entered in the corresponding positions (pos_1, pos_2, pos_3) of the table, BUT with the condition that the RESULTS of this search do not DISTANCE from each other more of 10 POSITIONS per ID as you can see what I do with the fragment:

```
and T***.id >= T***.id - 10
        and T***.id <= T***.id + 10
 and T***.id != T***.id )
```

Up to here everything is correct, the problem is that when making this query as it is done the RESULTS that I returned are the SELECTS independently from each other, that is, it only shows me the data I consult individually GROUPED SELECTS of the others ... I mean you are omitting ALL the results that intermingle the rows of the 3 SELECTS if that is the way it should be because it appears in the table. I'm getting the results SEPARATELY and I need the SELECTS to be united as a single SELECT and do not separate me and divide the results into three different SELECTS ... and I have no idea how to accommodate the query to do so ... Sharing the condition that the results do not differ from each other by ID more than 10 positions and jointly FOR EXAMPLE the result line of the SELECT nº1 is within the line of the result of SELECT Nº2 or Nº3 if it should be because it is so In the table.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question, but it sounds as if you might want to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` so that all rows from each `SELECT` are present in the output. Providing sample data and expected output would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your attention. The example at the end is simply that the result of each of these 3 selects is not separated and independent among them, but that the results of the 3 are intermingled as if it were a single broad selection.
And with the same condition that the 3 share that the results do not have more than 10 id positions between them.

If I ask you to do the search for the rows:
1st SELECT: 0 - 1 - 4
2nd SELECT: 2 - 4 - 8
3rd SELECT: 3 - 5 - 6

What you will do right now, as the query is done, will show me this:

```
82  0   1   4
83  0   1   4
86  0   1   4
```

On the other hand:

```
16  2   4   8
20  2   4   8
24  2   4   8
```

And on the other:

```
256 3   5   6
260 3   5   6
262 3   5   6
```

If you look at the results, apparently they are correct because they are showing me what I have asked for and also the results are grouped by an id that is not more than 10 positions apart.
But, this omitting all the results that are mixed and so appear in the table as for example would be:

```
82  0   1   4
84  3   5   6
86  0   1   4
89  3   5   6
--- --- --- ---
90  3   5   6
91  2   4   8
```

This last result would be correct since it would be located in the table, the lines are as they are supposed to appear in the list of data and only shows me that group of rows BECAUSE IT IS THE ONLY ONE OF ALL THE POSSIBLE THAT IS NEARLY NEXT GROUPED BY ID = 10.

Comment: It's an answer bummi, but when I passed the characters I had to put it as a comment. If there is another way to show it more appropriate, I do not know it.